# Syntax for adding GeoServer / GeoWebCache WMTS or TMS tiles to QGIS as XYZ Tiles layer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, geowebcache, wmts, tile-map-service

I am trying to add tiles from a GeoServer instance (using GeoWebCache) as an XYZ layer to a QGIS project.

The demo map on the server is here:

https://gis.lmi.is/geoserver/gwc/demo/LMI_Kort?gridSet=EPSG:3857&format=image/png

There are at least two URLS where I can access tiles individually:

- https://gis.lmi.is/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?layer=LMI_Kort&style=default&tilematrixset=EPSG%3A3857&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image%2Fpng&TileMatrix=9&TileCol=299&TileRow=408
- https://gis.lmi.is/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/LMI_Kort/EPSG:3857/9/408/299?format=image%2Fpng

The server also provides a TMS endpoint: https://gis.lmi.is/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0

I have tried variations of each of those as XYZ sources in QGIS, substituting {z}, {x} and {y} in the place of 9, 408 and 299.  I have also tried {-y}, to see if that works.  The projection for the project is 3857.  In all cases, I can add the layer to QGIS but nothing happens on the map canvas.

What is the correct connection string to use?

*Note:* I am able to add the layer as WMTS, but there are issues with the rendering.  I wanted to see if XYZ tiles would be better.  See [Image quality and aliasing effects in GeoWebCache WMTS tiles in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337529/image-quality-and-aliasing-effects-in-geowebcache-wmts-tiles-in-qgis) for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use this URL https://gis.lmi.is/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?Service=WMTS&Request=GetCapabilities&Version=1.0.0

For a WMTS, you need to replace after the base URL (all the url before `?`) the string with the following `Service=WMTS&Request=GetCapabilities&Version=1.0.0`

So, in your case, `https://gis.lmi.is/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?layer=LMI_Kort&style=default&tilematrixset=EPSG%3A3857&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image%2Fpng&TileMatrix=9&TileCol=299&TileRow=408` becomes `https://gis.lmi.is/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?` and after adding the end with my first instruction, you get at the end https://gis.lmi.is/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?Service=WMTS&Request=GetCapabilities&Version=1.0.0

You paste the URL by going to menu "Layers" > "Add Layer" > "Add WMS/WMTS Layer" > "New" (if you did not already configure "something") and fill the content with the previous URL (see screenshot) and click "OK"

[image: WMTS configuring in QGIS]

Then, "Connect" to get a list of layers like below screenshot. Choose one, "Add" and you will see the layer

[image: WMTS layers list]

End result in QGIS

[image: QGIS layers demo]

PS: except I've illustrated with your case, my answer covers more or less what is in the QGIS WMTS doc https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_client_support.html#wms-wmts-client. Feel free to visit it as it may help you to better understand

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this detailed answer. I was already able to add the layer as a WMTS, my problem was that there were problems with how it was rendered.  This was why I wanted to try the tiles directly.  In the end, I solved the problem with the "Zoom to Native Resolution" function on the WMTS layer.

See here for details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/375135/64762

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be here under "Fonction projecion de Mercator" : http://randochartreuse.free.fr/mobac2.x/mapsources/Islande/Islande-LMI_Kort.bsh